# Retrieving entities by checking a filtered subset of childen

Tags: sql, group-by, criteria-api

I have entities of the following structure:

```
@Entity
public Class MyObject {
    ...
    public List<Status> statuses;
    ...
}

@Entity
public Class Status {
    ...
    public Long creationTime;
    public Double range;

    @JoinColumn(name = "myObject",
            nullable = false,
            unique = false,
            updatable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    private MyObject myObject;
    ...
}
```

I got `n` entities of the type MyObject which can have `m` statuses. Ownership lays on the side of the Status entity which cannot be changed. I am currently trying to filter the entities that are greater-equal than a certain range. My current query retrieves a result for every status that has a range that is greater-equal than the one given as a parameter:

```
final CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
final CriteriaQuery<MyObject> cq = cb.createQuery(MyObject.class);
final Root<MyObject> myObject = cq.from(MyObject.class);
final Root<Status> statuses = cq.from(Status.class);
final Predicate[] predicates = {
    cb.equal(myObject.get(MyObject_.id), statuses.get(Status_.myObject).get(MyObject_.id)),
    cb.ge(statuses.get(Status_.range), range)
};

cq.select(myObject).where(predicates);
return entityManager.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
```

Desired is, that I only get the entities of MyObject, for which the most current status that has a range is greater-equal than the one given as a paramter. I am pretty sure that I have to group the list of statuses first and sort by creation time but I am not really sure how to combine all of this, especially not in the Criteria API.

**EDIT:**
At least I was able to create a SQL query that does what I want:

```
SELECT * FROM MyObject O INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM Status WHERE Status.CREATIONTIME IN (SELECT MAX(Status.CREATIONTIME) FROM Status WHERE (Status.RANGE IS NOT NULL AND Status.RANGE >= 30) GROUP BY Status.myObject)) S ON O.ID = S.myObject;
```

I am trying to rebuild this query using the Criteria API but don't really know how to include the embedded SELECT in the JOIN. Any help would be appreciated!